# Jquery selector parent without children

Tags: jquery, html-table, selector, onclicklistener

How do you select a container while omitting some elements in it?

I am trying to make an html table's cells clickable, but the div in these cell must not follow the click event. These divs may have links. I set the selector as below and everything within the cell is clickable.

```
 $('table').on('click', 'tr td', function(){
            alert('clicked');
 })
```

Now, I change the selector to not include div inside the element td, but this does not work: no part of the cell responds to any click.

```
 $('table').on('click', 'tr td :not(div)', function(){
            alert('clicked');
  })
```

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fo1eL8tb/

How do I make the cells clickable but not the div in the cells. If possible, I want to avoid stop propagation because the divs in the cells can have other event listeners.

EDIT

[HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/9bzmz/3/) is an example of what I am want. A div within the parent is left out of the click event.

Comment: There is not any links in div with jsfiddle, as you mentioned in your question.

Comment: @HimanshuUpadhyay sorry I omitted that. the content of the div may contain anything.

Answer (score 2):

> How do you select a container while omitting some elements in it?

That's not possible. The DOM is a tree structure. If you select one node, then by proxy you are selecting all its child nodes too.

That being said you can achieve what you require by checking exactly what element caused the event handler to run, and then performing the required logic. Try this:

```js
$('table').on('click', 'tr td', function(e) {
  if (!$(e.target).is('td'))
    return false;

  console.log('clicked');
})
```

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 10px;
  min-height: 200px;
}

td div {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Tes</td>
    <td>
      <div>this is inside a <a href="foo.html">div</a></div>
      Not inside div
    </td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

As you can see from this example, the `console.log()` will only be called when the click event is not fired from the `div` element within the `td`.

Comment: If there will be `<a>` inside `td -> div` then will this approach work ?

Comment: Yes, it will stop any events that did not originate from the `td`.

Comment: But if `a` is clicked, its parent <td> will get the click event, so your if condition will be bypassed.

Comment: No it won't. See the `return false;`? If you run the snippet you can literally see it working.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thank you for your input. But how is that different from this: http://jsfiddle.net/9bzmz/3/ . In this example, an element in the parent is left out of the click event

Comment: The difference there is that the `:not()` means that the event fires for every element except the `.delete-server` div. It would still run for it's children though - as you can see if you click the `<a>` in this example: http://jsfiddle.net/9bzmz/325/. My solution above works for any child at any level of the excluded element.

Answer (score -1):

Try to do this when click on the div return false

```
$('table').on('click', 'tr td :not(div)', function() {
  alert('clicked');
});

$('table tr td div').on('click', function() {
  return false;
});
```